# How does Firebase make App Indexing without web-site?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-indexing

I make my app for goods ads. I put all products to Firebase.
But there is a problem to create goods search. I have not other server than firebase. But queries in firebase for android are too elementary,
and my idea was to use Firebase Indexing for Google Search-Bot. My idea is to search all goods via google search like this:

[image]
But I also do not have a web-site.
I tried this URL_BASE = "http://recipe-app.com/recipe/", from the google example.
I added this to my code for indexing:

```
//THIS IS NOT MY WEB-SITE, BECAUSE I HAVE NOT IT....
public static final String URL_BASE = "http://recipe-app.com/recipe/";

 private void indexNote() {
// Note note = mRecipe.getNote();
Indexable noteToIndex = Indexables.noteDigitalDocumentBuilder()
        .setName(titleEditText.getText().toString())
        .setText("Added new product")
        .setUrl(URL_BASE + "/product")
        .build();

Task<Void> task = FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(noteToIndex);
task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(MY_TAG, "App Indexing API: Successfully added note to index");
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Log.e(MY_TAG, "App Indexing API: Failed to add note to index. " + exception
                .getMessage());
    }
});
}
```

Added this to gradle:

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

And this to manifest:

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://recipe-app.com/recipe" -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="recipe-app.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But it does not work. I am trying to search product name via google search, and I don't get the link to my app as a result. 
What am I doing wrong? Could anyone help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you just can't do it. Basically this links just telling system, that your app can open them. But they aren't real links, they doesn't even need to direct you to some website. So again, you can't make `search index` from `app indexing` because it's simply works other way.

Comment: I think so too, probably. Just fed hopes.

Comment: @Sergey Did you try https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url ?

Comment: Also, worth considering that it's take about month to site to get into google search indexing system. So, maybe your app is indexing, but you'll know it later.